# C# console application save excel file (do not prompt)

Tags: c#, console-application, export-to-excel

I want to write a console application where I will pull data into a dataset. I then want to save the file to a local hard drive. I have the code in my webapp which prompts the user to save it, but I would like to save it to local hard drive of the server and send email to user. Here is my code so far:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Test.xls;");
Response.Charset = "";

System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
dg.RenderControl(htw);
Response.Write("<style>.fraction { mso-number-format:#\\/#; }</style>");                   
Response.Write(sw.ToString());

Response.End();
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Excuse me? Can you please reform the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user is being prompted to save the file by the browser, not by your web app. If you have a locally executing console application, you can bypass all of that and simply open a [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h0z48dh.aspx) for writing, and associate your `HtmlTextWriter` with that. It would only prompt the user to overwrite if you explicitly wrote the code to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This console app works on schedule and create reports automatically and send an email with attachment so no user interaction or prompt is required. I will look into filestream and htmltextwriter.

Comment: Ok, so I created a filestream and store the data with tab delimited file. When user opens in Excel, excel automatically converts the tab into columns.  The other answer is kinda correct too but that requires excel file on the server that creates file and stores into server's hard drive. If you want to format the column and font and do calculation in the excel file then need to use Interop Excel.

Answer (score 0):

This is a snippet from a console app of mine, it saves a file without a prompt from the user.  You must add a COM reference for Excel.

```
    private void btnExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        app.Visible = true;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];
        int i = 1;
        int i2 = 1;
        foreach (ListViewItem lvi in lvwResults.Items)
        {
            i = 1;
            foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem lvs in lvi.SubItems)
            {
                ws.Cells[i2, i] = lvs.Text;
                i++;
            }
            i2++;
        }

        wb.SaveAs(String.Format(@"C:\MyReportABC-{0}-{1}", String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd}", DateTime.Today), String.Format("{0:hhmm}", DateTime.Now)));
        wb.Close(true);
    }
```

Outputs a file named MyReportABC-20120621-0539.xls (changes on everytime, you could add a user ID in the string as well)

Comment: Thanks for the code but this requires excel on the server. It won't work if there is no excel installed. If I can't find the solution then this would be the last resort.

Comment: You said a console app, and also saving to a local drive.  So, what server?  Whoever uses it will need Excel on their desktop, but that's practically a given these days.  This doesn't require Excel on any server if you use it in a console, winform or wpf app.